# Where to ask strategic questions?

Tags: feature-request

It would be nice if there was a place to ask strategic questions related to the business behind a software project.

On Stack Overflow I just posted my first question: "in-app-purchaseable items browseable in iTunes?". Now the question has been closed, and I have been told to ask it on Super User. However, Super User seems to be targeted to end users, and there is not even a single question yet tagged "in-app-purchase".

Answer (score 2):

How about [startups.com](http://www.startups.com)?

> The place to grow your business one question at a time. It's THE website for business people, entrepreneurs, small business owners, home-based businesses to ask business questions.

Comment: Thanks - could be an interesting resource!